# How can the covariance of 1xn score function be computed for fisher information

Tags: covariance, fisher-information

Fisher Information can be calculated using the covariance of score function. For logistic regression the log-likelihood is taken to obtain the score function which is

```
 YX - PX              // Y-class X-record P-htheta
```

On computing the result of this I get a 1xn matrix. And I am confused how to calculate the covariance of this score function. I know how generally a covariance matrix is calculated but I am stuck with this 1xn. Please help.